# Python: Can we assert "in" and "not in" in a string?

Tags: python, selenium, assert, assertion

I have this code that I need to check whether `partialExpectedTitle` is included in `documentTitle` . But I get an error afterwards that we have an assertion error. Does `in` and `not in` only work in a list? Or do I make it work in a string?

```
documentTitle = context.mailTrapPage.getExcelTitle().text.strip()
excelTitle = download_path + "/" + documentTitle
excelWorkbook = o.load_workbook(excelTitle)
print("partialExpectedTitle is " + partialExpectedTitle)
print("documentTitle is " + documentTitle)
assert partialExpectedTitle in documentTitle is True
```

Error:

```
      assert partialExpectedTitle in documentTitle is True
  AssertionError
  
  Captured stdout:
  ['1 - AAAAAA qlgmdfol']
  partialExpectedTitle is courses20220913_1110
  documentTitle is courses20220913_111050.xlsx
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Guy . But quick question, when to know whether we add `is True` to an assertion? :o

Comment: You never add `is True`, it's pointless. `assert` will pass or fail when given bool. There is no point in checking it's value again.

Comment: Hi @Guy thank you for that. Is it the same for adding `is False` ? How do we check something if it's disabled? Like, `assert elementLocator.is_enabled is False` or do we have a better way of writing it?

Comment: What about `assert not elementLocator.is_enabled`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of [operator chaining](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons), the expression `x in y is True` is equivalent to `(x in y) and (y is True)`, which is probably not what you had in mind.

So when do you need `is True`? Hardly ever. It only makes sense when you need to distinguish the actual value `True` from a ["truthy"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false) value such as 17 or "hello".

For your example in a comment, use the `not` operator: `assert not elementLocator.is_enabled`.

Comment: Ohhhhhh. That makes it so much clearer. Thank you so much for the correction (@)Guy and @Ture Pålsson :)